# How to get a specific Visual Studio version

Tags: visual-studio

As part of our TFS build I would like to gather versions of our build environment to document under what circumstances it was build. The specific Visual Studio version might not have a great impact on the build process, but it wouldn't hurt to have the right version.

In the about box I see "Version 14.0.25425.01 Update 3" but Product/File Version on devenv.exe is 14.0.25420.1. In the registry under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0 there are also not much help.

The Product/File Version on C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\msenv.dll has the right version, but is this one the correct to look at?

Can I somehow programmatically get the 14.0.25425.01 that I expect?

Comment: It's strange to have VS installed in your build agent. It makes more sense to gather SDK version.

Comment: @qxg: Visual Studio is installed to ease the deployment of new build servers. It would of cause be more correct to install specific SDKs and log their version, but the Visual Studio install serves as a collection of the right things. That way we can easily recreate a server with 'same' build environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no official documentation.

From my personal research (for a similar purpose):

The version number resides in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\ProductUpdate\SplashInfo.pkgdef". 
Please note that the file *do not seem to exist* if no update is installed.

(Additional Info: 
The value seems to be copied into the registry value HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0_Config\SplashInfo\EnvVersion at the first time you launch devenv.exe. The about box shows the value of the above registry value. By removing the registry value, you will see "14.0.25420.1 D14REL" in the about box, which seems the version of devenv.exe.

Because the registry value does not exist until you launch devenv.exe, I think SplashInfo.pkgdef is a more reliable choice.)

Comment: We are getting a bit of different results here. On my machine the About Box, SplashInfo.pkgdef and the registry EnvVersion has the same value. But one of my colleagues has "14.0.24720.00 Update 1" in the registry and "14.0.25425.01 Update 3" in the About box and SplashInfo.pkgdef. So it seems that SplashInfo.pkgdef is the best solution so far.

Comment: @ToreØstergaard Possibly your colleague runs devenv.exe as a different user (specifically as Administrator). If so, the registry value EnvVersion in that user's registry is the value actually used.

Comment: I agree with you that SplashInfo.pkgdef is the better choice. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The following code shows "16.0.29306.81 D16.2" in my VS 2019:

```
var shell = (package as System.IServiceProvider).GetService(typeof(Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.SVsShell)) as Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsShell;
object ver = null;
shell.GetProperty((int)Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.__VSSPROPID5.VSSPROPID_ReleaseVersion, out ver);
System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(ver.ToString());
```